# Problem uninstalling SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, 64-bit, uninstallation

I have a problem with SQL Server 2005.

I have a Computer with Windows 7 x64 bits installed and I want to run SQL Server 2005 correctly. The first time I try it, i did the follow:

1) Install SQL Server 2005
2) Install SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 x64

And it works!

But now (for reasons that are irrellevant) I need to uninstall all and re-install again to check the steps.

So I went to Add/remove programs of Windows and uninstall all the SQL Server things that I found. After, I did the same steps that I said before, but... it didnt work! What's going on?

I saw that the uninstall of SQL Server 2005 seems that it didnt go well because i can find the instance of SQLExpress... and i read that Service Pack of SQL Server cant uninstall.

But... how can remove ALL SQL Server 2005 things, to start again the installation like i did the first time?

Thanks

Comment: I already fixed the problem! It was hard but i finally get the answer here: http://www.agileit.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?Id=190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to remove the instance you can see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967/en-us) how to do it manually. Another resources is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/50164862-ef20-4758-9c7a-0d6ae8f1b3f9/) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx).

Comment: My god... there is not an easy solution to uninstall it? Seems that i have to work with microsoft to uninstall sql server...

Comment: These documents describes how to uninstall manually. As I remember, If you want to remove all installation, you just need to use the SQL distributive, run setup.exe and then, after some pressing of "next" button, select the features to deinstall.

Comment: can you explain that a little more? The sql distributive only allow to install the program, not to uninstall...